# How do I recreate /var/log/audit with the right permissions?

Tags: fedora, logs, selinux

Since my disk space was running out and I saw it was using up several gigabytes, I decided to delete everything in `/var/log/*`, thinking they're just log files and it should be OK to delete.

I manually ran a `sudo mkdir /var/log/audit`. However, [when running an `ausearch` command](https://bl.ocks.org/thoroc/c988aaed65b5450fd61bd19c44885a8d), I'm getting the following output.

```
Error opening /var/log/audit/audit.log (No such file or directory)
```

How do I recreate this folder and file with the right permissions, attributes, etc?

I'm using Fedora 34.

Answer (score 1):

`ausearch` searches through the audit log at `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. It not being present causes the error.

Probably, the `sudo mkdir /var/log/audit` didn't set the correct permissions. It should be

```
drwx------.   root root system_u:object_r:auditd_log_t:s0      /var/log/audit
```

A `sudo chown root:root /var/log/audit && chmod 0700 /var/log/audit` should take care of that.

You can force the correct SELinux permissions with `restorecon -Rv /var/log/audit/`.

Restart the audit daemon afterwards with `systemctl restart auditd.service`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment so will note that Edward's info above is SLIGHTLY incorrect:  auditd cannot be restarted with systemctl.

Restart Auditd with "service auditd restart" (or start, stop, etc.)